# javascript animate not working on safari nor firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, cross-browser

I have a javascript animation in my code that seems to work in chrome but not in safari or firefox. However when I created the fiddle, and ran the fiddle in both safari and firefox, it works. https://jsfiddle.net/dspoknvv/1/ I have jquery configured in my app, so that isn't an issue. Code in question:

```
var l = 20;  
for( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
    $('.input-field').animate( { 
        'margin-left': "+=" + ( l = -l ) + 'px',
        'margin-right': "-=" + l + 'px'
 }, 50  ); 
}
```

I have tried deleting that chunk of code and put an alert there just to make sure my app was hitting that chunk of code, and the alert box did indeed appear.

Comment: And in your app the code is inside `$(function(){...})`  or `$(document).ready(function(){...})`  ?

Comment: it is inside an if else statement. This is in a js.erb file

Comment: the if else statement is in ruby

Comment: does the failing animation leave behind a style attribute like `margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;` on the element?

Comment: @yezzz nope, doesn't seem to be the case. The link to this demonstration is [link](https://climate-iq.com/) if you scroll all the way down to the email subscription footer. On chrome, when you enter an invalid email it will animate but any other browser, the animation will fail.

Comment: Right now I'm seeing it work in IE, but not in chrome or firefox. What happens is that the hidden input is targeted. Remove the hidden type and you'll see it move in the other browsers.

Comment: And it does leave behind a style attribute.. check your console again

Answer (score 1):

Check that your script targets the correct input. As it stands, on some browsers it animates an hidden input.